# Tikz Spacing after horizontal line

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I'm trying to draw an ornament after a horizontal line, with a small spacing between the figure and the line, but `xshift` doesn't seem to work when I connect the line to a node.

I'm attempting to do this

```
\draw ([yshift=-10pt]current page header area.south west) -- %
([xshift=-5pt,yshift=-10pt]current page header area.south); %
node {\pgfornament[width=0.5cm]{1}};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this? Notice the options `remember picture,overlay` for `tikzpicture` (thanks to **Paul Gaborit** for reminding me of this):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw ([yshift=-10pt]current page header area.south west) -- %
([xshift=-5pt,yshift=-10pt]current page header area.south) %
node[xshift=20pt] {\pgfornament[width=0.5cm]{1}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You had a spurious `;` before the node.

Perhaps is it something like this what you have in mind?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw ([yshift=-10pt]current page header area.south west) --
([xshift=-15pt,yshift=-10pt]current page header area.south);
\draw ([xshift=15pt,yshift=-10pt]current page header area.south) --
([yshift=-10pt]current page header area.south east);
\node[yshift=-10pt] at (current page header area.south) {\pgfornament[width=0.5cm]{1}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw ([yshift=-10pt]current page header area.south west) --
node[fill=white,inner xsep=10pt] {\pgfornament[width=0.5cm]{1}}
([yshift=-10pt]current page header area.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The precaution mentioned in the answer to [How to avoid empty space caused by TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68720/3954) might be useful too.

Comment: I think that the `remember picture` and `overlay` options may be useful here.

Comment: @PaulGaborit You are absolutely right; I'll add them right now.

Comment: You may also add a link to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68720/how-to-avoid-empty-space-caused-by-tikz.

Comment: @PaulGaborit link added. Once again, thanks.