# Why is an overlay tikzpicture introducing extraneous vertical spacing before a section?

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}%
\definecolor{sidebar}{RGB}{220,62,136}%
% \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]%
%     \fill[sidebar] (current page.north west) rectangle ([xshift=2cm]current page.south west);%
% \end{tikzpicture}%
\section*{Title}%
\end{document}
```

This renders as expected:

[image]

However, if I uncomment the `tikzpicture` I get this:

[image]

Why does the `section` get pushed down and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Good question, +1. As a *workaround* you could put the overlay picture after the section, obviously it would not change the position of the picture. I also feel that [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22873/121799) is very closely related, and I leave it to you and non-gold-badge cursed users to decide whether yours is a duplicate thereof.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68720/14500

Comment: A overlay tikzpicture is a box, a small box but nevertheless a box, so it can change spacing.

Comment: @Ulrike Hence the second part of my question: how can I prevent it?

Comment: As marmot wrote: put the tikzpicture in a place where such a box doesn't harm, e.g. in a paragraph with test and not somewhere where it builds a paragraph on its own.

Comment: The `tikzpicture` is not unique in this behavior. A `\marginpar` has the same effect even though may expect it shouldn't. Try `\marginpar{x}%
\section*{Title}%` to see what I mean. There it is arguably even worse since it does matter where you issue the `\marginpar`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm already using the suggested workaround (thanks!). I just thought maybe there was a more elegant means of controlling this. But this being LaTeX, I guess not :)

Comment: You can also use \rlap or \llap to avoid leaving vmode.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68720/how-to-avoid-empty-space-caused-by-tikz), a `tikzpicture` creates a small box and calls a `\leavevmode`. The box itself does not take up any space with the `overlay` option active, but the mode change does. However, other content such as text induce the same mode change. As such, to get rid of the problem, place the picture where content is already to be added. The example below illustrates this.

Coloured nodes are added in each picture to illustrate the placement of the box and to show how it does not influence or interfere with the text.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\definecolor{sidebar}{RGB}{220,62,136}%

\begin{document}%
    \section*{Title} % section without text, without tikz
    \section*{Title} % section with text, without tikz
        text
    \section*{Title} % section without tikz, with text
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
        %\node[fill=green,inner sep=2cm] (n2) {};
        \node[fill=red] {};
        \fill[sidebar] (current page.north west) rectangle ([xshift=2cm]current page.south west);%
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \section*{Title} % section with tikz, with text (= same)
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
        \node[fill=blue] {};
        \fill[sidebar] (current page.north west) rectangle ([xshift=2cm]current page.south west);%
        \end{tikzpicture}%
        text
    \section*{Title} % final section
\end{document}
```

[image: induced leavevmode]

Comment: Note that in the current state of Ti*k*Z, when using `baseline` and `overlay` at the same time, it is [possible](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/344) that a `tikzpicture` adds to the height or depth of the enclosing box.